# Marathon: Placement Constraints in Mesosphere Jobs

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

How can I add **Placement Constraints** in mesosphere jobs? 
I know there a [GUI way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3f8R.png) to add this to **Services** and what I need is how can I do the same to [JOBS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYMbD.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but maybe not exposed in GUI. See below example from [readme](https://github.com/dcos/metronome/blob/6a0b3e21b0a6aa66553c037b4ab1216547b392c0/README.md#example-job-with-placement-constraint)

```
{
   "id": "sample-job",
   "description": "A sample job that sleeps",
   "run": {
   "cmd": "sleep 1000",
   "cpus": 0.01,
   "mem": 32,
   "disk": 0,
   "placement": {
       "constraints": [
    {
        "attribute": "hostname",
        "operator": "LIKE",
        "value": "<host-name>"
    }
       ]
   }
   },
   "schedules": [
        {
            "id": "sample-schedule",
            "enabled": true,
            "cron": "0 0 * * *",
            "concurrencyPolicy": "ALLOW"
        }
    ]
}
```